# Accidently deleted Profiles and Stubs4 from Django and unable to run manage.py

Tags: python, django

I wanted to clear the database because I messed in putting correct parameters to `update_or_create` and `create` functions of django.For that I deleted the database from pgadmin4 in postgres and deleted all__pycache__, stubs.v4 and the Profiles folder in my django project because I wanted to again feed data into the database.

My goal is to upload a .csv file and fill data row by row (create/update) to database.
Now these errors neither let me `create superuser` not let me do run `manage.py`

```
PS C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\github\DjantoSoft> python manage.py runserver
c:\python37\python.exe: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

PS C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\github\DjantoSoft> django-admin createsuperuser
No Django settings specified.
Unknown command: 'createsuperuser'
```

Comment: stubs.v4 is regenerating on its own.

Comment: as the error says, there is no `manage.py` file to run, so you may have been deleted it accidentally. you need to recover it.

Comment: yes, I saw it just now. The shell refreshed and all my cd>cd>cd reseted. I was outside to where manage.py was located. Thanks. I m deleting this question cause its a bad one.

Comment: But can I get help on how to clear database easily?

Comment: it depends on which dbm you use, so for SQLite, just delete the file, for MySQL and PostgreSQL drop data base like `drop database MyDataBase`

Comment: I got a stackoverflow post which says to use "python manage.py flush".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As told by @aasmpro, the error was that in Visual Studio Code I was out of the folder where manage.py was located.
Also, to empty database   `python manage.py flush` should be used instead.